# It is possible to make a flux field checkbox checked?

Tags: typo3, backend, flux

I create a Checkbox in Flux for Typo3

```
<flux:field.checkbox label="Feste Höhe" name ="settings.hoehe" />
```

It is possible to set this checkbox checked per default?

[image: What I see]

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it

```
<flux:field.checkbox label="Feste Höhe" name ="settings.hoehe" default="1"/>
```